# How should I fix the bad request response I am getting when sending a POST request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to log on a site using python (Requests) and keep getting 400 Bad request error.

I have tried different header formats, even copied the headers from different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) but I am always getting 400 error.

I've tried browsing around but can't find anything that would help me.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://developer.clashofclans.com/api/login'
    e='xxx@xxx.xxx'
    p='yyyyy'

    header = {'authority': 'developer.clashofclans.com',
                'method': 'POST',
                'path': '/api/login',
                'scheme': 'https',
                'accept': '*/*',
                'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'accept-language': 'en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
                'content-length': '57',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'cookie': 'cookieconsent_status=dismiss',
                'origin': 'https://developer.clashofclans.com',
                'referer': 'https://developer.clashofclans.com/',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
                'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    login_data = dict(email=e,password=p)
    x = c.post(url,data=login_data,headers=header)
    print(x)
```

Comment: What does the Clash of Clans API documentation say?

Comment: Do you really need all that stuff in the headers?  `method`, `path`, etc?

Comment: @JohnGordon There isn't anything regarding this in API documentation, maybe I should provide some background,

Comment: Send a _good_ request instead?

Comment: I need to login and generate new API token whenever my IP changes because I have a dynamic IP and the token is based on IP. I want to automate this process but in order to do that I need to log into my account first.

Comment: I don't really know what all I need in headers, I've tried just sending the data without headers and it returns 403, if I just keep 'content-type': 'application/json' in. It gives 400

Comment: @mustaccio How do I do that?

Comment: Okay this is kinda weird, I was able to solve it by referring to Requests documentation, apparently some websites accept the data as json dumps. so replacing " data = login_data" with "data = json.dump(login_data)" worked.

Answer (score 0):

some website expected the data as json format. in requests you can easly do this by using json params, so your code will be something like this:
`python
x = c.post(url, json=login_data, headers=header)`